# How to use the Array find function to return an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this Homework that requires me to pass a parameter  called userID to an arrow function. Inside this function, I am required to use the .find function on an array called users. this find function should return an object containing the userID. Here is the full instruction :

> Create a **getSelectedUser** arrow function above
>   **displaySelectedUser**. It should take a **userId** parameter and use the Array .find function on the **users** collection to find and
>   return the selected user object. Your .find call should take an inline
>   arrow function and de-structure its parameter to obtain the id
>   property.

the **users** is an array: **users** =

```
[{
  age: 50,
  weight: 55,
  height: 6,
  country: 'US',
  name: 'Bob Manuel',
  id: 'ehriuiuye'
},
{
  age: 20,
  weight: 80,
  height: 6,
  country: 'UK',
  name: 'Michael Lawrence',
  id: 'fjikijd'
}];
```

**what I have done**

```
const getSelectedUser  = (userId) =>{
    users.find(element => element.id === userId);
};
```

Now, the auto-grader returns this error:

> Create a "getSelectedUser" function that returns the selected "user
>   object". See the instructions for details.

Is there anything wrong with the function I created?

Comment: The answer will depend on what language you are using, which you neglected to identify.

Comment: From the assignment and sample code I would guess this to be JavaScript (arrow functions, destructuring, triple equals sign for comparisons `===`)

Comment: 1) you didn't return anything 2) not sure a semi colon goes at the end of a JS function, Hope this helps - WWC

Comment: I’m sorry it’s JavaScript

Comment: @Wookies-Will-Code you're right of course, nothing is returned. The semicolon is fine though ;)

Comment: @buboh I rewrote the code to use destruction const getSelectedUser  = (userId) =>{
         
       return users.find(({id}) => id === userId);
      };   but it's still not workin

Comment: You could even shorten the solution to: `const getSelectedUser= (userId) =>users.find(({id}) => id === userId);`. The result is not very easy to read though...

Comment: Great, that you got it to work! Please accept an answer, if your question has been answered ;)

Comment: Please do *not* put the answer inside your question. Instead mark an answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```js
const getSelectedUser = (userId) => users.find(({id}) => id == userId)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess what could be missing is the "destructuring" mentioned in the instructions. Destructuring is the process of assigning selected properties of an object to variables. For example, if you have an object

```
const foo = { 
    bar: "hi",
    baz: "friend"
}
```

you could either access it’s properties via `foo.bar` and `foo.baz` or by destructuring the object with

```
const {bar, baz} = foo;
```

which would define two variables `bar` and `baz`.

In your case you could do the destructuring instead of specifying the `element` parameter of the arrow function.

**Edit:** 
As was pointed out in a comment, you're not returning anything from the `getSelectedUser` function. You would need to do `return user.find(element => ...)` or maybe `return user.find(({id}) => ...)`

**Edit 2:**
The full code should be:

```
const getSelectedUser = (userId) => {
    return users.find(({id}) => id === userId);
};
```

or the short version:

```
const getSelectedUser = (userId) => users.find(({id}) => id === userId);
```

Comment: If I do the destructuring, I will get the userID in a variable. What do I do with it?

Comment: You could replace the `element` variable and subsequent `element.id` property access in your inline arrow function with a destructuring expression `({id}) => ...`

Comment: Thanks. I’m still confused . How do I return the object after destruction (to get the ID). I’d appreciate if you could help write the code.